# Retorno estranho ao chamar uma função

Tags: python

Estou tentando fazer um exercício sobre funções, no Python, com o seguinte enunciado: "Faça um programa que converta da notação 24 horas para a notação 12 horas". Exemplo: Converter 14:25 para 2:25 PM. O programa deve conter duas funções, uma que converta a hora e outra que imprima a hora (com AM ou PM).

Eu cheguei até certo ponto, mas agora estou com dúvida do porquê o programa não esta rodando.

Meu programa:

```
hora = int(input("Digite a hora: "))

minuto = int(input("Digite os minutos: "))

def converter_hora(hora):

         return (hora -12)

def imprime_hora(hora,minuto):

        if(hora <= 12):
           print(hora,minuto,"AM")
        else:
           print(converter_hora,minuto,"PM")

print(imprime_hora)
```

O Python esta devolvendo a seguinte mensagem:

> function imprime_hora at 0x02D8C0C0

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer uma chamada de uma função, você deve colocar o nome da mesma, seguido de parenteses. Se a função possuir argumentos, os valores destes devem ser especificados entre os `()`. No seu caso, você quer invocar a função `imprime_hora`, que possui os argumentos `hora` e `minuto`, então a chamada da função deve ser algo como:

```
print( imprime_hora(14, 25) )
```

Como, neste caso, os valores de `hora` e `minuto` são lidos do usuário, você deve fazer:

```
print( imprime_hora(hora, minuto) )
```

O mesmo acontece quando você invoca a função `converter_hora` em:

```
print(converter_hora,minuto,"PM")
```

Você deve informar o valor do argumento `hora` desta forma:

```
print(converter_hora(hora), minuto, "PM")
```

Aliás, considerando que a própria função `imprime_hora` já imprime o resultado, não é necessário fazer `print( imprime_hora(14, 25) )`, basta apenas fazer `imprime_hora(14, 25)`.

O código final, já corrigindo os **erros de indentação**, fica:

```
hora = int(input("Digite a hora: "))
minuto = int(input("Digite os minutos: "))

def converter_hora(hora):
    return (hora -12)

def imprime_hora(hora,minuto):
    if(hora <= 12):
        print(hora,minuto,"AM")
    else:
        print(converter_hora(hora), minuto, "PM")

imprime_hora(hora, minuto)
```